# It seems ConcurrentBag is not Thread-Safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

I had written a program that a list-builder method returns IEnumerable of string including lots of strings (1milion items) and I stored it in List of string , then it append all the items in a StringBuilder instance in a **Parallel.Foreach**. Then I printed **stringBuilderInstance.Length** .

The problem was that it was fewer than 1000000 .
after some [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877358/multiple-threads-adding-elements-to-one-list-why-are-there-always-fewer-items-i?rq=1), I realized thet List collection is not Thread-Safe , and that causes this problem.
So 2 solution crosses my mind :

1) Use **lock**

2) Use **ConcurrentBag**

When I am using lock , it is OK and the length is 1 milion , BUT :

**when I am using ConcurrentBag of string , the length is fewer than I expected !**

What is the underlying reason of this problem?

List-Creator method :

```
public static List<string> CreateList()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        result.Add(1.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using ConcurrentBag :

```
public static void DoWithParallel_ThreadSafe()
{
    ConcurrentBag<string> listOfString = new ConcurrentBag<string>(CreateList());
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    Action<string> appender = (number) =>
    {
        a.Append(number);
    };
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfString, appender);
    Console.WriteLine($"The string builder lenght : {a.Length}");
}
```

Using lock :

```
public static void DoWithParallel_UnsafeThread_Lock()
{
    List<string> listOfString = CreateList();
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    Action<string> appender = (number) =>
    {
        lock (listOfString)
        {
            a.Append(number);
        }
    };
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfString, appender);
    Console.WriteLine($"The string builder lenght : {a.Length}");
}
```

Main :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoWithParallel_UnsafeThread_Lock();
    DoWithParallel_ThreadSafe();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to learn more about threading before trying to write thread-safe code.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Comment: Just so you know Parallel.ForEach calls the IEnumerable you pass in to the first argument in a thread safe way, so it does not matter what collection you used to pass in for that argument.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain : If Parallel.Foreach call the IEnumerable  in a thread-safe way , why this problem happens ?

Comment: @Parsa Did you read the two answers at all? The problem is not caused by the IEnumerable, it is caused by StringBuilder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringBuilder` cannot be mutated from multiple threads, hence why the code doesn't work when you try to do that.  Note that locking is pointless; just don't create multiple threads to do the work in the first place since the work can't be done from multiple threads.  Since you're never accessing the `ConcurrentBag` from multiple threads, so it's pointless to be using that instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 5):

`StringBuilder` is *not* thread-safe, which is why some `Append()` calls are "lost". So you still need the lock, even if your collection is thread-safe.

(Also, see Servy's answer for why you don't need the collection to be thread-safe at all.)

Comment: You shouldn't be locking here.  The correct solution is to just not create multiple threads, rather than to create a bunch of threads only to synchronize all of them.

Comment: But when I use string instead of stringbuilder , it gives me the wrong answer too , the string is thread-safe. am I correct ?

Comment: @Parsa: String is immutable; your variable is not thread-safe.